# Why is this square not square?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using html canvas to create a simple square. The dimensions for this square are outlined with the following code:

```
myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "green", 1, 1);
```

However, even though I gave the square the dimensions of 30 by 30; the square on my screen clearly looks like a rectangle.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/erpYRe?editors=0010)

I think the problem has to do with how I am calling the new game piece into existence in the JS code but Im not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing your CSS for the canvas.

Comment: @maxpaj Yes that worked https://codepen.io/hoyos/pen/erpYRe?editors=0100 post your comment as an answer so I can check you off.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have width and height se in your CSS class, if you remove it will became an square.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you just define the width and height in pixels. Because your screen is probably not a square because the pixel ratio is for example 1920 by 1080 pixels the square looks like a rectangle. You need to get the ratio of width to height and use it as factor for the width or height. For example you have a screen with 200x100 px. The ratio of width to height is 200/100. So your square has to be 20 px wide and 20/2 = 10px high.